# vscode problem matcher issues when using WSL to build on cmd.exe

Tags: gcc, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-tasks, vscode-problem-matcher

I am writing code in WSL using a remote session and then building on cmd.exe. The build process works fine but I cannot get the problem matcher to link to the correct files.

I change my cwd

```
"options": {
    "cwd": "/mnt/c/Freescale/CW MCU v10.6.4/eclipse"
  },
```

Below is my build cmd

```
 "cmd.exe /c ecd.exe build -data $WORKSPACE_LOC -project $PROJECT_LOC"
```

Problem matcher looks like

```
"problemMatcher": {
    "base": "$gcc",
  }
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this. I have tried using relative and absolute paths.

Comment: Does the build task actually output the error lines, or does it just produce an output file?

Comment: I think it produces an internal file and uses a regex-based problem matcher to parse data.

Comment: Not asking about the problem matcher, asking about ecd.exe.  The problem matcher consumes standard output from the command (cmd.exe /c ecd.exe ...).  So, if ecd.exe is writing the output to a log of it's own, then the problem matcher won't see it. There isn't really enough detail for me to tell for sure, but I'm guessing you need to run a build.cmd file that does ecd.exe ... and then "cat"s that to the stdout so the command in the task list sees it.